# Ember Data 'find' with parameters prevent new record from displaying

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to add new record to Ember Data store, and it expected to be displayed immediately. Spent few hours trying to figure out why it isn't displayed, and found, that passing parameters to Ember Data store.find prevents it.

So this code works:

```
App.FlagsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('flag');
  }
});

App.FlagsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  init: function() {
    this.store.createRecord('flag');
  }
});
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/409/edit

There is one new record in the bottom of the table being displayed, as expected.

And when I'm adding only one thing, the params to 'find' query, it stops working.

So this code breaks new records diplaying:

```
App.FlagsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('flag', params);
  }
});
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/407/edit

New record actually added to Ember Data store, but not shown in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're creating a record in the `init` function of your controller. Your route's `model` hook is called before your controller is instantiated for the first time, so it's not finding the record because it doesn't exist. The first one works because the `find` method called with no parameters returns an array that updates as new records are added. Calling it with parameters doesn't do that.

Your `init` function is a terrible place to create records anyway. You shouldn't be dealing with any kind of persistent state in that function. Ideally, records should be created in controllers, at runtime, as the result of user interaction. If you give us a little more information about your use case and how you want to create a new flag, I can help you a bit more.

Comment: I supposed that init() is wrong place, and tried to add objects as result of user interaction. Still doesn't work: http://jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/411/edit. My use case is to create object and pass it to modal form without transition to 'new' controller or something like this.

Comment: You're still calling `find` with parameters, meaning that the array won't update as changes are made. Change your model hook to just return `this.store.find('flag')` and it'll work.

Comment: Finding with parameters is exactly what I need. Can't change that, because in my use case the parameter is date, and server returns data subset for specific date.

Comment: Well there's really no way for Ember-Data to know if a newly created record is going to fit your query or not (at least not without some pretty complicated logic). You're just going to have to re-query the store when you know a new item has been added.

Comment: That's seems the point. Actually, I don't need complex logic. Just some way to say Ember: "add it to collection and don't care if it don't fit". As a workaround, I will use new collection, which displayed separately: http://jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/419/edit